# Git / Gitlab : How to set a multi-user or multi-project configuration

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to configure Gitlab / Git in multi-user and multi-project mode on linux

I have two local repositories

**The problem:**

If I create a repository specifying the login in the url, the local config will contain this credential, and we can only use this one. So we lose the ability to know who push what in the remote

```
git clone https: // login@ url / xxx/ yyy.git
```

**The bad solution:**

Respecify the remote in the global config => we will not be able to work on other repositories

**The ideal solution:**

We should be able to clone a directory without specifying the user in the url:

```
git clone https: // @ url / xxx/ yyy.git
```

Git would ask the user / passwd every time

Except that Gitlab does not allow it; make the following error:

```
git clone https://url/xxx/yyy.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing https://url/xxx/yyy.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your current `git` version installed on your local machine.

The command for that would be: `git --version`

Make sure you have git 1.7.10 or later. After that version it should prompt for the username and password.

The Gitlab remote URLs are (without the specific user name):

- HTTPS: `https://domain/owner_name/repository_name.git`
- SSH: `git@domain:owner_name/repository_name.git`

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use the latest version of git. Try to install that. After that, you will be able to clone it.